# In thunderbird I do not want it to automaticly open new email

Tags: email

I have a dell with windows 7.  As soon as I click on an email it opens in the window below. I do not want this to happen, how do I change this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Mozilla Thunderbird to start up by displaying a website in the lower-right pane, instead of the content of an email.

Tools --> Options --> General

https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/configuration-options-startup

(edited to correct the URL for my answer)

Comment: Sorry - the iPad's crazy copy-n-paste got me again.    Here's the correct URL for my comment.                                            https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/configuration-options-startup

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to hide the message preview pane that takes up the bottom half of the screen by default in Tbird. This would allow you to see a full-screen list of all your emails, but no message content until you actually open an email.

In my Tbird (v 17.0.3), I can turn the message pane off by pressing F8 or going to Options > Layout > Message Pane.

If we have the wrong idea please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Account Settings > Server Settings and uncheck "Check for new messages at startup." That's it.

Frank D

Comment: I think what he's looking for is a way to shut off the preview feature, this looks more like a way to prevent Thunderbird from actually checking for mail on startup.